# fftw in C++ gets slower for power of 2?

Tags: c++, fftw

I'm working with the fftw library in C++. I know that the calculation of the fft is most efficient for powers of 2, but I created a minimal example of a two-dimensional fft and I get a different result. The 2d-fft with no power of 2 is calculated much faster than the other one. Here is my code:

```
int N = 2083;
int M = 2087;
int Npow2 = pow(2, ceil(log2(N)));
int Mpow2 = pow(2, ceil(log2(M)));

fftw_complex * signala = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* N * M);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        signala[i*M + j][0] = rand();
        signala[i*M + j][0] = 0;
    }
}

fftw_complex * signala_ext = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* Npow2 * Mpow2);

fftw_complex * outa = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* N * M);
fftw_complex * outaext = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* Npow2 * Mpow2);

//Create Plans
fftw_plan pa = fftw_plan_dft_2d(N, M, signala, outa, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_plan paext = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Npow2, Mpow2, signala_ext, outaext, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

//zeropadding
memset(signala_ext, 0, sizeof(fftw_complex)* Npow2 * Mpow2); //Null setzen
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        signala_ext[i*Mpow2 + j][0] = signala[i*M + j][0];
        signala_ext[i*Mpow2 + j][1] = signala[i*M + j][1];
    }
}

//Execute FFT
double tstart1 = clock();

fftw_execute(pa);

double time1 = (clock() - tstart1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time: %f sec\n", time1);
double tstart2 = clock();

fftw_execute(paext);

double time2 = (clock() - tstart2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time: %f sec\n", time2);
```

I choosed prime numbers for N and M. My programms returns:
For signala (non-power-of-2): 2.95 sec
For signala_ext (power-of-2): 5.232 sec

Why is the fft with power of 2 so much slower? What have I done wrong?

I will be thankful for any help!

Comment: I must be missing something here. The non-power-of-2 case runs an FFT of 2083*2087 while the power-of-2 case runs an FFT of 4096*4096.

Comment: So to a first-order approximation, the POT FFT takes half as long per element (this is the well-known improved efficiency) but processes 4 times as many, for a total time that's twice as long.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, thank you!! But that means I can't improve the speed by choosing the next power of 2? Or is there another method to make a faster fft?

Answer (score 1):

FFTW likes dimensions which are products of powers of small primes. The nearest value above 2083 or 2087 which meets this criterion is 2100 (2100 = 2<sup>2</sup> * 3 * 5<sup>2</sup> * 7), so if you go for dimensions of 2100 x 2100 then you should see decent performance.